# Problem 16.4 on related vector fields Differentiable Manifolds Marcut

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

In the course I am taking on differentiable manifolds, we have been using the [notes written by Marcut](http://www.math.ru.nl/~imarcut/index_files/lectures_2017.pdf) . This problem caught my attention as it seemed pretty straightforward.

> Consider the map:
>   $$\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2,~ \phi(x,y):=(e^xcos(y),e^xsin(y))$$
>
> 1. Find two vector fields $X,~Y~\in~\mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $X$ is $\phi$-related to $\partial_x$ and $Y$ is $\phi$-related to $\partial_y$. Are these vector fields uniquely determined by this condition?. Calculate $[X,Y]$
> 2. Find two vector fields $U,~V~\in~\mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\partial_x$ is $\phi$-related to $U$ and $\partial_y$ is $\phi$-related to $V$. Are these vector fields uniquely determined by this condition?. Calculate $[U,V]$

**Solution**

I have found and checked the solutions for both parts.

For part a), I used the fact that the required condition is equivalent to $ \partial_x(\phi^*(f))=\phi^*(X( f)) \label{eq:related}$. I find $X$. Using the same procedure for $Y$, I get that: 
$$X = x\partial_x+y\partial_y,~ Y= -y\partial_x+x\partial_y$$
$$[X,Y]=0$$

For part b), I noticed that $U$ can be written as $U=u_1(x,y)\partial_x+u_2(x,y)\partial_y$. Using the condition that $U(\phi^*(f))_p=(\partial_u( f))_{\phi(p)}$, I find $U$. Using the same procedure for $V$, I get:
$$U= e^{-x}cos(y)\partial_x-e^{-x}sin(y)\partial_y,~V= e^{-x}sin(y)\partial_x+e^{-x}cos(y)\partial_y$$
$$[U,V]=0$$

So in summary:

- In part a), we are finding the pushforward of the coordinate directions: $$X=\phi_*(\partial_x),~Y=\phi_*(\partial_y) $$
- In part b), we are finding vector fields that correspond to the pushforward of he coordinate vector fields:
  $$U,~V~ \text{such that}~ \phi_*(U)=\partial_x,~\phi_*(V)=\partial_y$$.

Because the pushfoward has the property that $F_*[X,Y]=[F_*X,F_*Y]$, I know that the lie bracket in both cases should be 0, since $[\partial_x, \partial_y]=0$

My questions are:

- Is my summary of the problem correct?
- I am not sure if the vector fields in both cases are uniquely determined  by these conditions. I think they are uniquely determined by these conditions if $\phi$ was bijective. But that is not the case. How can I know if those fields are uniquely determined?

Comment: Whoa. $\phi$ is far from bijective.

Comment: That is right (corrected that in the question). The map$\phi$  is not bijective, it will cover $\mathbb{R}^2$ many times as $sin(y)$ varies.  Then, I have no idea about why those fields are uniquely determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the vector fields you found are correct, so I will only comment on the uniqueness. 
Note that the differential of the map $\phi$ is
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{1}
d_{(x,y)}\phi=\begin{pmatrix} e^{x}\cos y & -e^{x}\sin y\\ e^{x}\sin y & e^{x}\cos y\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
which is a linear isomorphism (its determinant is nonzero).

1. You found $X,Y\in\mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ such that for all $p\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$:
   \begin{cases}
   d_{p}\phi[\left(\partial_{x}\right)_{p}]=X_{\phi(p)}\\
   d_{p}\phi[\left(\partial_{y}\right)_{p}]=Y_{\phi(p)}.
   \end{cases}
   These equations determine $X,Y$ uniquely on the image of $\phi$. Since $\text{Im}(\phi)=\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, it follows by continuity that $X$ and $Y$ are uniquely determined.
2. Now you found $U,V\in\mathfrak{X}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ such that for all $p\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$:
   \begin{cases}
   d_{p}\phi(U_{p})=\left(\partial_{x}\right)_{\phi(p)}\\
   d_{p}\phi(V_{p})=\left(\partial_{y}\right)_{\phi(p)}.
   \end{cases}
   Again such $U,V$ are unique, since the differential \eqref{1} is injective.